# du -hs . is taking too long

Tags: centos, filesystems

```
ls -ltra
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 119 centos centos 14336 Oct 24 20:36 tasks
```

when I want to do recursive operations on this directory, It's stuck. taking forever.examples :

```
sudo chown apache:apache -R tasks/
```

when I use df

```
 df -h .
Filesystem                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
fs-4f1bd753.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:/  8.0E  331M  8.0E   1% /mnt/efs
```

I didn't set up this server. what does that last output mean?

Comment: 8EiB. Jeez.....

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: Network file systems rarely fulfill the expectations of operations per second that you would assume from working with local file system.**

The output says you are working on filesystem that is not local to the system you are working on. More specifically, this looks like `Amazon Elastic File System`.

You should check what applications wrote to that folder and verify if something went wrong - writing incredibly many zero-length files - or whether the application design simply does not fit what EFS can and cannot do.

Amazon EFS is NOT optimized for file operations per second. If you work with a number of files in the magnitude millions of files, you should often not be using EFS.
It has two modes, both perform awful if you work on very high number of files (to some extent, this is less about the amazon product and more about underlying protocol NFS4).

> In General Purpose mode, there is a limit of 7000 file system operations per second. This operations limit is calculated for all clients connected to a single file system. - [Limits for Amazon EFS File Systems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html#limits-fs-specific)